# What's the right spelling of "synchronized"?

Tags: verbs, orthography, past-participles, ise-ize

What's the right spelling of *synchronized* (like  in *synchronized swimming*), and are there any differences between the British and American English?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'syntax'. 'Syntax' refers to the order of words in a sentence and here you are only asking about a single word. Could this be a question about word-class (noun, verb, adjective, etc.)?

Comment: Teneff: Have you checked a dictionary? What did it tell you? Please share with us what you have already researched.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Syntax will come into play when you present a complete sentence. A single word cannot have a "correct" syntax. Differences between British and American English will manifest in the spelling. US will use "synchronized swimming", British English will use "synchronised swimming".

With regards to syntax, you may need to provide a bit more context to warrant a valid answer.

Answer (score 8):

British spelling is "synchronised" and American is "synchronized" so the correct spelling will depend on yourself and your intended audience.

Refer http://www2.gsu.edu/~wwwesl/egw/jones/differences.htm

Comment: Actually, both spellings are British. Most UK writers prefer the -ise form, but Oxford University Press strongly champions the -ize.

Comment: If the -ize form is preferred by the Oxford University Press, I would like to see a source added to the comment so it can be studied. Should you have one, could provide us with it please?

Comment: Most newspapers seem to go for the -ise form - https://ddg.gg/?q=synchronisation+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.economist.com  https://dgg.gg/?q=synchronisation+site%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.theguardian.com&ia=news

Answer (score 3):

Both are in common use in UK English.

Oxford University Press style is -ize in almost all cases: http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/03/ize-or-ise/

But their dictionaries accept either spelling.